# Why is my POST request creating URL Query Strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, url, post

I have a React program with a routing issue. I am using a POST Request for the registration System, and whenever I hit register, the user-entered password and email address and put up top in the URL which I do not want. I don't know why this POST Request is displaying such things in the URL. It's also just taking me to a blank page. I think that is an issue with .get('/');

This is the code that is invoked when I click "Register":

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                name: this.state.name
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => {
            if (user.id) {
                this.props.loadUser(user);
                this.props.onRouteChange('home');
            }
        })
    }
```

And here are all of the routes on the server:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.send() });
app.post('/signin', Signin.handleSignin(db, bcrypt));
app.post('/register', (req, res) => { Register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt) });
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => { Profile.handleProfileGet(req, res, db)});
app.put('/image', (req, res) => { Image.handleImage(req, res, db)});
app.post('/imageurl', (req, res) => { Image.handleApiCall(req, res)});
```

Does anyone know why it would be creating URL parameters? I didn't tell it to. The /signin route is also a POST Request but it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check your browser console to confirm it is actually being sent as a `POST` and not a `GET`. Having the data in the URL is an indication it is being submit as a GET via Form Submit. I do not thing it is at fault, but I'd change your method from `post` to `POST`. More likely, I suspect your form markup may be setup to be a GET and your custom fetch logic is not properly cancelling the form submit event.

Comment: Essentially, make sure you form has an `method="POST"` or use JavaScript to `e.preventDefault();` on the form `submit` event so you can handle the POST request via AJAX.

Comment: I se in the browser console that it is being sent as POST.

Comment: Can you share the Markup that produces the form fields and submit buttons in addition to what you have already provided?

Comment: Guys I added "method='POST'" to my form tag and the fixed the URL issue.... But now its sending me to the wrong page!

Comment: Your markup did not render in your last comment. Regarding being sent to the wrong page -- that's progress, it means it was what I was originally describing. You need to attach your event handler to the form `submit` event and then `event.preventDefault();` the native form handling the browser has (submit the data and go to that page).

Comment: Oh, I see you got it into the question body. Right, so you have `onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn}` on your submit button. This should instead be an `onSubmit={this.onSubmitSignIn}` on the `form` element. THEN you can cancel the default form event behavior.

Comment: I changed the form to a div and that fixed a lot of issues!

Comment: Sure, that'll work too, but it is not very semantically correct: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics

Comment: @SethMarks «*I added "method='POST'" to my form tag and the fixed the URL issue*». If that answers your question, you should tag the question as answered and, should you have a different problem, post a new question. When you edit the question code to fix it, you render the question meaningless and you frustrate people who help you.